# Using azure file storage with kubernetes and azure container service (aks) - permission denied

Tags: postgresql, azure, kubernetes, azure-storage, azure-container-service

I have an azure container service (aks) cluster. It is migrated to version 1.8.1. I am trying to deploy postgres database and use `AzureFileVolume` to persist postgres data on.

By default, if I deploy the postgres database without mounting volume, everything is working as excepted, i.e. pod is created and database is initialized.

When I try to mount a volume using the yaml below, I get **initdb: could not access directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Permission denied**.

I tried various hacks as suggested in this long [github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630), like: setting security context for the pod or running chown commands in *initContainers*. The result was the same - permission denied.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
    component: test-db
  name: test-db
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: myapp
    component: test-db
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-db
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        component: test-db
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 999
        runAsUser: 999      
      containers:
      - name: test-db  
        image: postgres:latest  
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false          
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: myappdb
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: myappdbuser  
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: qwerty1234
        volumeMounts:
          - name: azure
            mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data              
      volumes:
        - name: azure
          azureFile:
            secretName: azure-secret
            shareName: acishare
            readOnly: false
```

Comment: You specified `runAsUser: 999`, but remember that all Docker volumes will be [mounted as root](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259). This might lead to permission issues. Also, I experienced that kubernetes sometimes remounts the volume, so an initial `chmod` might not be enough.

Answer (score 2):

We came across the same problems and figured out the following solution:

Instead of using an *AzureFileVolume*, we used an **AzureDisk**. So what we needed in Kubernetes is the following...

**Storage Class**

[image]

With your Azure account name

**Persistent Volume Claim**

[image: Persistent Volume Claim]

**PostgreSQL Deployment**
Include PVC in the Kubernetes Deployment

```
- name: postgres-db
  persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc-postgresdb
```

Additionally we need to point the PGDATA var to a subdirectory of the mounted directory. Because Azure is creating some issues with the AzureDisk type in the base directory.

```
#... evn definitions... 
- name: PGDATA
  value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/
  name: postgres-db
```

Comment: Yes, I heard from different place that AzureBlob/Disk should be used instead of FileStorage. I'll give it a try again in the next days. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to message me on twitter (@lennartblom) for details (YAMLs, Azure settings). We stuck the last 5 days figuring this out... we are happy to help!

Comment: @LennartBlom are you running multiple replicas of postgres like this?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work you need to use azure disks, reason postgres uses hard links which are not supported by azure files
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/548